# Jquery select2 - How to disable options in one dropdown without affecting all other dropdowns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, razor, jquery-select2

This is what I'm doing:

```
$('select').each(function () {
        var selectedValue = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        if (selectedValue !== '0') {
            $('option').each(function () {
                if (!this.selected) {
                    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

The first option is "-Select an option-" that has a value of "0", that's why I do that validation. Basically what I want to do is to disable all options within a dropdown that has a selected value different than the first one. All dropdowns have been initialized with jquery's select2 and every one of them has a unique id.

The code I'm sharing doesn't work properly because I get the options disabled in every dropdown no matter if no option has been selected.

Can anybody help me fix this please?

Comment: You mean you want to disable all the options except the selected option when the selected value is 0?Why not try to disable the dropdown when the selected value is 0 with `if ($(this).val() != '0') { $(this).prop("disabled", true);}`?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested but you should replace this line:

```
$('option').each(function () {
```

with this one:

```
$(this).find('option').each(function () {
```

Also, you should call this function using change event, which means i'ts triggered when some option is selected, like this:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
```

The thing is that by doing this:

```
$('select').each(function () {
$('option').each(function () {
```

You were iterating through all select elements and all it's options, instead of iterating through the only select element that was clicked